# How to test the "smtp" validity of an email with python?

Tags: python, smtp, email-verification

Hello I have a list of multiple email addresses with custom domains (exemple: name@organisation.com).
 Some emails are valid others aren't.
 How can I programmatically test the smtp response of these emails with python?

Comment: There isn't really any reliable way to tell if an address is valid.

Comment: Define "valid'. Do you mean syntactically valid? Or that a mailserver will accept mail send to this address? Or that mail send to this address will be delivered to someones mailbox? Or something else entirely?

Comment: "Valid" in the sense that I can successfully send a message to that address. The receiver receives the message in its inbox.

Like when I send an email through gmail to a fake email. Gmail will respond with an error saying "could not send the message to that address" (imply the email is not valid).

I would like to automate that process for several addresses.